# ColdFusion Builder 2 Connection reset error when using ColdBox Platform Utilities extension

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder, coldbox

I have a DEV environment setup using CF10 and CFBuilder 2.

I have my webserver setup (IIS 7.5) and I have given write permissions to the wwwroot directory so I don't get prompted when trying to create files or directory.

When I try to run an extension for creating a CF project using the ColdBox Platform Utilities I eventually get an error.

The error is: Connection Rest and the Java Stack Trace is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.adobe.ide.coldfusion.appcodegeneration.runtime.HTTPRequestSender.httpRequest(HTTPRequestSender.java:61)
    at com.adobe.ide.coldfusion.appcodegeneration.runtime.CFMHandler.callHandler(CFMHandler.java:191)
    at com.adobe.ide.coldfusion.appcodegeneration.runtime.CFMHandler.performExecute(CFMHandler.java:129)
    at com.adobe.ide.coldfusion.appcodegeneration.runtime.CFMenuHandler$1.run(CFMenuHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I have never had this problem before with CFBuilder or the ColdBox tools.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

SocketException:

> Thrown to indicate that there is an error creating or accessing a Socket.

So it has to do with TCP... Check firewall, port, ip ... etc.